# Delete the FTP file after used in file import

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

How to add a step in Marketing cloud automation workflow to delete the FTP file automatically after using for import to data extension when expecting a new file drop everyday.

Comment: why does it need to be deleted? the new file drop will simply overwrite the existing file

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Data Extract activity of type 'Delete file from ET FTP or Safehouse', first you need to enable it in your account if you didn't do.